# Cannot install updates on wubi

Tags: wubi

I installed a wubi on my optiplex gx 620 recently on top of a windows xp. But after using it for about two weeks, I notice that the software update can never be carried out again. Every time I log in the system reminds me to do updates, but when I press the update button it flashes out a temporary message box (for about half a second) saying there is some authentication error (I can't get the complete message since it's too fast). This didn't bother me too much until today when I want to install foreign language support. The same flash message box appeared again and the installation cannot be done. After waiting for about 5 minutes a message box pops out saying "time out most likely the daemon died".
 I can give more details but I thought this might be a generic problem with wubi installation?

updates: after following the advice of fossfreedom, I think the upgrading is up and running! Before I only typed in sudo apt-get update, but I guess it's important to do upgrade as well! Thanks a lot!

My only lingering concern is how to do this upgrading automatically outside terminal. It seems there should be a way to enter password in a GUI? It would also be nice because sometimes I don't know the name of a particular software (like a language package) so it's easier to just upgrade in a GUI.

Comment: belongs on ubuntu

Comment: please can you run in a terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` - post the results of the output into your question.

Comment: @user - Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu - can I suggest you register with this stackoverflow site with your current credentials.

Comment: Hi @fossfreedom, thank you for the suggestion. I am now registered. Could you take a look at my updated question as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open the dash and type *update manager* will display your Update Manager.  Click the Settings button (bottom left)

[image]

You can set the frequency of updates and well as what you update as shown by the arrows in the picture.

Open the dash again and type *startup applications*

[image]

Make sure that update notifier is checked - this will then automatically run update manager according to your update frequency defined above.